# SharePoint 2010 modify web.config file with http handlers

Tags: sharepoint

I am deploying a SharePoint 2010 web part that uses the microsoft .net charting tool to build charts. I need the chart handler added to the sharepoint web.configs automatically. I've been told that when you create the wsp the package can be told that when the program is installed it needs to modify the web.config to add these handlers.

I have seen a couple options out there:
-WebConfigModifications 
-Safe controls

I don't know which, if any, that I should be using. I don't know for sure if this will be a first time installation for the application (we're moving sharepoint environments at the same time we are updating this. I think that it will be a first time installation on that new environment but can't be sure.)

And I definitely do not know how to implement this correctly. I would appreciate any advice.

Also it may be important  to know that I do not have any privileges on the server. I can't even deploy myself.

For example, this seems like good info: http://platinumdogs.me/2009/07/08/using-the-mschart-controls-in-sharepoint-moss-2007/ Except that I can't just write to the webconfig and restart IIS. It has to be automated and not a direct edit to the file.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a **[Feature Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureReceiver(v=office.15).aspx)** attached to your WSP to create the appropriate **[SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification(v=office.15).ASPX)** entries when your solution's features are activated. Likewise, the SPWebConfigModification entries should be removed when your solution's features are deactivated.

### Step 1: Create a Feature Receiver

MSDN has an overview of how to add a Feature Receiver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx

Note you'll want to handle both the [FeatureActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featureactivated(v=office.15).aspx) and [FeatureDeactivating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeaturereceiver.featuredeactivating(v=office.15).aspx) events.

### Step 2: Use Feature Receiver events to add or remove SPWebConfigModifications

In those two events, you'll need to programmatically add or remove one or more SPWebConfigModification entries. These affect SharePoint's web.config file, but unlike a manual edit of the config file, they are stored in SharePoint's content database. This means that if the web.config is reset for any reason (and it happens), SharePoint can and will reapply the modifications, thus preserving your changes.

MSDN has an overview of programmatically creating and removing SPWebConfigModifications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861909(v=office.14).aspx

It is very important that the FeatureDeactivating event properly clean up all modifications made during FeatureActivated, or you will end up with a proliferation of duplicate config entries. This means you need to really understand how to use the **[Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.path(v=office.15).aspx)** and **[Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.name(v=office.15).aspx)** properties of the SPWebConfigModification.

This article gives a good overview of how Path and Name are combined to create an XPath expression pointing to the node to be added or removed: http://smindreau.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/finally-the-way-to-add-web-config-modifications-to-sharepoint/

### Step 3: Test, test, TEST!

Lastly, test activating and deactivating your solution's feature in your local development environment to make sure everything is working properly. Note that the modifications will be applied via a timer job, so you may need to wait a minute or two to see the changes show up. ***Be sure the feature deactivation cleans up your modifications!*** (If you get into a mess in your development environment with duplicate modifications, you can always wipe the slate clean with a little [PowerShell action](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2012/08/23/how-to-remove-a-web-config-modification-using-powershell.aspx).)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Took me a while to get it set up right but it's working perfect now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. It is a little tricky to get things right, but it's an incredibly useful technique once you've figured it out.